# Android Retrofit 2 - Cannot pass string inside onResponse callback

Tags: android

I want to concatenate/append a string inside the onResponse callback of Retrofit2

Global Variable

```
Boolean isSaved = "false";
String message = "";


    Queries queries = Server.getClient().create(Queries.class);
    Call<ResponseModel> responseModelCall = queries.products(param1, param2);

    responseModelCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseModel> call, Response<ResponseModel> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                if(response.body().getCode().equals("1")) {
                    message = "Success";
                    isSaved = true;
                } else {
                    message = "Failed";
                    isSaved = false;
                }
            } else {
                    message = "Error";
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

    if(isSaved){
        Toast.maketext(getActivity, "Congrats: "+message, LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.maketext(getActivity, "I am sorry: "+message, LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

if the data is saved then the toast is
"Congrats: "

if not 
"I am sorry: "

I noticed that the string I passed from the onResponse did not work. But the boolean did work.

Comment: Move your if condition on onResponse

Answer (score 3):

If you want to show a toast, you should put it inside `onResponse`.

```
responseModelCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseModel> call, Response<ResponseModel> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                if(response.body().getCode().equals("1")) {
                    message = "Success";
                    isSaved = true;
                } else {
                    message = "Failed";
                    isSaved = false;
                }
            } else {
                    message = "Error";
            }

            if (isSaved){
                Toast.maketext(getActivity, "Congrats: "+message, LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.maketext(getActivity, "I am sorry: "+message, LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, the Toast is just an example, I am needing that String into something else. BTW, I got a solution. I passed it inside a void/method/function (i dont know what to call it, im confused doing php android c#, makes me wonder why I choose to be programmer). Anyway, thanks for the effort.

Comment: @Maki Did you mean `callback` or `listener`? it's the better way for expandability! do not confuse, couz your question will help other programmers. thank you!

Comment: The question is why you cannot use the string appended inside the onResponse even if the string is declared as a Global Variable. Likewise, you can use the boolean appended inside the onResponse.

Answer (score 1):

Just put that condition of Toasts inside the OnResponse  so that the Toast will be Triggered.